# Plural pronoun for the word sushi

Tags: grammar, word-choice

I found that sushi is defined as a mass noun which means it is uncountable so the plural form for sushi would be still sushi. In that sense imagine this dialog:

- Hey, do you like some sushi?
- Yes, I like them.

Is it correct to use “them” in this specific case? Or should I use “it” instead?

What about water? It is also uncountable noun but we use “it” with it.

Comment: Edited for clarity. It is not would you like but do you like instead. Do you think “Yes I like some” still applies? Because I have only two options between it and them.

Comment: Note that you can have many different waters, cheeses, breads... *Sushi* is probably affected by being a foreign word and seems to connote all the different types available in a sushi bar, in the manner of a collective noun.

Comment: "Do you like some sushi?" is a rather strange question.  We would probably only say, "Do you like some *kinds* of sushi?"  And the answer to that could be, "Sure, I like some [kinds]" or "No, I don't like any [kind of] sushi."

Comment: *Do you like sushi?* is a general inquiry, not an invitation. *Would you like (some) sushi?* is an offer to eat or order sushi now. "Do you like to dance?" "Yes, I go when I can." "Would you like to dance?" "Sure, is this a Salsa?"

Comment: Do you want to say: "Do you like sushi?" "Yes I like it" or, as Yosef Baskin said, "Would you like some sushi?" "Yes I'd like some." Those (and Juhasz's suggestion for a 'rather strange question') are your options.

Comment: You could use "them" to identify specific pieces of sushi, e.g. if you're in a restaurant or pointing at a menu. "Yes, I like those ones." This is different to water, where you wouldn't normally want to pick out specific water.